# Cannot compile a Gradle project with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am trying to set up a gradle project to function in Eclipse, but when I try to import it or run a gradle build, the build simply fails silently. I'm seeing the error below in Eclipse's Problems tab, but don't know what to make of it. It mentions a directory of "C:\Eclipse", but that directory doesn't exist, and because this project is at work, I don't believe I have permission to create it. I suspect this is a simple problem and that I just don't have enough experience with Gradle to figure it out. For all I know, the directory not existing is the problem. I know the project builds on its own using the wrapper from the command line correctly, and thus believe the issue is mainly with how Eclipse is configured.

```
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run phased build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.EclipseModelUtils.runPhasedModelQuery(EclipseModelUtils.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.EclipseModelUtils.runTasksAndQueryCompositeModelWithRuntimInfo(EclipseModelUtils.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.EclipseModelUtils.runTasksAndQueryModels(EclipseModelUtils.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.DefaultModelProvider.lambda$null$4(DefaultModelProvider.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.DefaultGradleBuild$GradleConnectionOperation.runInToolingApi(DefaultGradleBuild.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager$WorkspaceRunnableAdapter.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2322)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.DefaultGradleBuild.withConnection(DefaultGradleBuild.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.DefaultModelProvider.lambda$fetchEclipseProjectAndRunSyncTasks$5(DefaultModelProvider.java:74)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4873)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.DefaultModelProvider.getFromCache(DefaultModelProvider.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.DefaultModelProvider.executeOperation(DefaultModelProvider.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.DefaultModelProvider.fetchEclipseProjectAndRunSyncTasks(DefaultModelProvider.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.DefaultGradleBuild$SynchronizeOperation.runInToolingApi(DefaultGradleBuild.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager$WorkspaceRunnableAdapter.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2322)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.DefaultGradleBuild$SynchronizeOperation.run(DefaultGradleBuild.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.DefaultGradleBuild.synchronize(DefaultGradleBuild.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.SynchronizationJob.runInToolingApi(SynchronizationJob.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.workspace.SynchronizationJob.runInToolingApi(SynchronizationJob.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.ToolingApiJob$1.runInToolingApi(ToolingApiJob.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager$WorkspaceRunnableAdapter.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2322)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.run(DefaultToolingApiOperationManager.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.operation.ToolingApiJob.run(ToolingApiJob.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not set process working directory to 'C:\Eclipse': could not set current directory (errno 2)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcess.setWorkingDirectory(DefaultProcess.java:52)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcess.setWorkingDirectory(WrapperProcess.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.processenvironment.NativePlatformBackedProcessEnvironment.setNativeProcessDir(NativePlatformBackedProcessEnvironment.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.processenvironment.AbstractProcessEnvironment.setProcessDir(AbstractProcessEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.processenvironment.AbstractProcessEnvironment.maybeSetProcessDir(AbstractProcessEnvironment.java:89)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: The command `errno 2` returns 
*_ENOENT 2 No such file or directory*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. It turns out that creating an empty "C:\Eclipse" directory solved this problem. Don't know or care how.